# Use values from Google Sheet to populate Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms

I'm trying to make a form to help manage tasks. I want to be able to derive form values from values already in a spreadsheet, and use the spreadsheet to add or manipulate the values that appear in the Google Form. For example, the chore list would look something like:

```
| Assignment     | Due Date  | Assignee  |
------------------------------------------
| Take Out Trash | Tuesday   | JonMitten |
| Wash Dishes    | Monday    | Baby Bear |
| Undermine Auth.| Tuesday   | Unassigned|
```

With the unchangeable value "Assignment" and "Due Date" but where the form user may assign a job task to him or herself.

I would want to be able to add Assignments and Due Dates and Assignees via the spreadsheet, and have the form pick those select menus from a sheet range.

Is this possible?